# how to print log.info message in log file

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, log4j

I need to know how to print a log.info message. I have no knowledge about using loggers. But I tried this code using netbeans and this didn't work. here is the code:

```
public class login {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("myFirstLog");

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        initLogger();
        LoginUser();
    }

    public static void LoginUser() {              
        log.info("user logged in");
    }

    public static void initLogger() {
        try {
            String filePath = "E:/myFirstLog.log";
            PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%-5p %-10d %m %n");

            RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, filePath);
            appender.setName("myFirstLog");
            appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
            appender.activateOptions();

            Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A log file is created with no log information.How to fix this code to get info messages in log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the default logging level is `Level.ERROR`, which means that only calls to `log.error()` (and nothing else) will result in log information being recorded.  You need to configure the log level you actually want, e.g. by adding this:

```
appender.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
```

This means your logger will output every message from INFO priority and above. Of course you could put a lower level such as `Level.DEBUG`.

### EDIT

On the other hand, your log is not static, but is is used from static methods, so you need to change it.

Comment: I didn't realized that logger is not static and he is using it statically, edit my answer.

Comment: No, I think you may be correct.  Can you provide a link to some documentation showing what the default logging level is?

Comment: Ah! ok, not sure where this is documented, but default level is error `Level.ERROR`.

Comment: I changed the code.but still nothing changed. I get an empty log file

Comment: `RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, filePath);
            appender.setName("myFirstLog");
            appender.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
            appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
            appender.activateOptions();`

Comment: Did you also change logger declaration? It has to be static, other way it won't work.

Comment: the log file is created. but with nothing.when I add log.warn and log.fatal messages, those messages records in log file. but even with the code you mentioned, info messages won't be recorded

Comment: I found the code. It's `LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG)`